# Next.js page is automatically scrolling to top (only on mobile)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm doing my first project with Next.js and I'm facing a weird behaviour. I mean that webpage is automatically scrolling to top. This issue occurs only on mobile. I'm kinda confused. Previously I had sth like this:

Parent Component:

```
const someRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
return (
    <ChildComponent ref={someRef} />
)
```

Child Component:

```
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((_:unknown, ref: React.LegacyRef<HTMLElement>) => {
    return (
      <div ref={ref} id='someRef'>
          // ...
      </div>
    )
 }
)
```

Currently I've removed all refs & replaced forwardRefs by React.FC and code looks like:

Parent Component:

```
return (
    <ChildComponent />
)
```

Child COmponent:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
    return (
      <div id='someRef'>
          // ...
      </div>
    )
}
```

On desktop everything works fine, but as I mentioned - the issue occurs only on mobiles.

Edit2:
I've removed all the Link elements and this behaviour still occurs. Previously I also tried different ways, sth like:

```
<Link href={`#about`}>about</Link>
<Link href={`/page1#about`}>about</Link>
<Link href={`/page1/#about`}>about</Link>
<button onClick={() => router.push('/page1#about')}>about</button>
```

Edit:
This is how the Link element looks like:

```
<Link href={`/page1/#about`}>about</Link>
```

Comment: You scroll down on page and do nothing, and it is scrolling to top? I think this is not related to nextJS it has only auto scrolls after navigation what I know https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link.

Comment: Exactly, it occurs even before using any link. I was thinking that could be caused by using refs/forwardRef but removing refs didn't help. What's more - it occurs randomly.